# Fazer escolha via combobox das tabela do BD para inserir dados

Tags: php, mysql

Exemplificando:
 **Escolha** nas **opções** em qual das **tabela** do Banco de Dados você quer **inserir** suas informações.

```html
<!---
EXE: Banco de Dados
CREATE TABLE tabela_acao, tabela_comedia, tabela_ficcao(
  id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   nome varchar(20) not null,
   genero varchar(20) not null,
   clasificacao varchar(20) not null,
);
--->

EXE: Tabela que vai inserir conteudo no BD
<form action="" method="">
   <label for="id1">Nome do Filme</label>
    <input type="text" name="nome" id="id1" required>
   <label for="id2">Genero do Filme</label>
    <input type="text" name="genero" id="id2" required>
   <label for="id3">Classificação do Filme</label>
   <input type="text" name="clasificacao" id="id3" required>
   <input type="submit" value="Adicionar">
</form>

EXE: combobox que vai determinar em gual tabela os filmes ira ser colocados
<select>
    <option>tabela_acao</option>
    <option>tabela_comedia</option>
    <option>tabela_ficcao</option>
</select>
```

Comment: para podermos ajudar vc deve postar seu código ou algo que vc tentou fazer e ate mesmo sua estrutura de banco. não so isso mas tbm vc deve formular uma pergunta mais direta.

Comment: Pelo que entendi ele quer marcar o combobox e com isso fazer o select no banco.

Comment: É tipo assim: Eu cadastrei um filme com o gênero de comédia, ai eu escolho em qual tabela vou colocar! entenderam? @Jasar Orion

Comment: por que vc nao separa as categorias e grava os filmes na mesma tabela? tipo tabelas filmes e vc tem um campo categoria que grava qual categoria o filme pertence.

Comment: @Jasar Orion, porque não dar certo, o que eu quero fazer não é tão simples assim, e só vai funcionar com as categorias em tabelas diferentes.

Comment: me explica o q vc quer fazer então pois ao meu ver não tem diferença pois o mysql é modular o suficiente para vc manipular os dados da forma q quiser.

Comment: @pedroandre  por favor não adicione RESOLVIDO, no titulo, o site funciona diferente de fóruns. você pode aceitar uma das respostas clicando no `v`  a esquerda delas, ou caso tenha achado a solução por conta propria, pode publicar sua solução. Visite [tour] e veja como o site funciona.

Answer (score 1):

o seu código de inserção no mysql seria este

cod html

```
<form action="?acao=grava" method="post">
   <label for="id1">Nome do Filme</label>
    <input type="text" name="nome" id="id1" required>
   <label for="id2">Genero do Filme</label>
    <input type="text" name="genero" id="id2" required>
   <label for="id3">Classificação do Filme</label>
    <input type="text" name="clasificacao" id="id3" required>
   <input type="submit" value="Adicionar">
</form>

EXE: combobox que vai determinar em gual tabela os filmes ira ser colocados
<select name='tabelas'>
    <option value='0'>Ação</option>
    <option value='1'>Comédia</option>
    <option value='2'>Ficção</option>
</select>
```

php que vai ficar antes ou depois do form

```
if($_GET['acao']=="grava"){
   $categoria=array('tabela_acao', 'tabela_comedia', 'tabela_ficcao');
   $sql="INSERT INTO ".$categoria[$tabelas]." set nome='".$_POST['nome'].", genero='".$_POST['genero'].", classificacao='".$_POST['classificacao']."";
   mysqli_query($con,sql);
   echo "dados adicionados";
}
```

isso faz exatamente o que vc pediu.

Comment: eu vou testar seu código, mas eu vou criar o código no JSFiddle pra te mostrar exatamente o que eu pretendo, ok.

Comment: olha lá <a href="https://jsfiddle.net/userHTML/9gcy6xer/#&togetherjs=RaI4rvDuUQ">Exemplo</a>

Comment: ainda nao entendi pq precisaria ser tabelas diferentes.